# Custom user permissions on table in Hasura

Tags: permissions, hasura

I'm developing an app which requires custom permissions on a specific table. I have the following data structure:

```
Users
  -> id
  -> name

Accounts
  -> id
  -> name

UserAccounts
  -> userId
  -> accountId
  -> permissionLevel
```

`permissionLevel` is an enum and could be: `Owner`, `ReadAndWrite` or `ReadOnly`.

What I'd like to have is the following:
1) If you're an `Owner` of a `UserAccount`, you can invite other users.
2) If you want to create a new `Account`, you'll get the `Owner` permission in `UserAccounts`.
3) You can not add yourself to `UserAccounts` when you are not the `Owner` of said `Account`.

The issue I'm having is I'm  not sure on how to solve this in Hasura. I've tried the following Hasura permission (but I'm missing an option to expand the `where` clause (see below)):

```
{
    "_or": [
        {
            "_and": [
                {
                    "accountId": {
                        "_is_null": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Account": {
                        "UserAccounts": {
                            "_and": [
                                {
                                    "userId": {
                                        "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "permissionLevel": {
                                        "_eq": "Owner"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_not": {
                "_exists": {
                    "_table": {
                        "name": "Account",
                        "schema": "public"
                    },
                    "_where": {
                        "UserAccounts": {
                            "accountId": {
                                "_eq": "$accountIdFromQuery" // <-- this does not exist AFAIK
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm at a loss what direction to go. Maybe I'm just missing something, maybe I need to use a custom [view](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/role-multiple-rules.html) or maybe I need to try a custom postgresql function. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For now, my solution is using an event trigger (which triggers an AWS Lambda function) to write into the `UserAccounts` table with admin privileges. Hasura has documentation on how to achieve this: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/event-triggers/serverless.html